# Return index by comparing two string arrays in C#

Tags: c#

Lets assume we have two string arrays

```
string[] array1 = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
string[] array2 = {"bb", "aa", "cc", "bb", "aa", "cc"};
```

now the string bb in array2 is in second position of array1 so the output should be 2

aa in array2 is in first position of array1 so the output should be 1

cc in array2 is in third position of array1 so the output should be 3

bb in array2 is in second position of array1 so the output should be 2

so on..

all these output index positions should be stored in an array..

any idea how to accomplish this in C#.net?

Comment: please share your ideas - what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int[] indicies = array2.Select(n => Array.IndexOf(array1, n)).ToArray();
```

This will project the elements of `array2` as a sequence of their indicies in `array1`, and convert the result to an array.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the original requirement was that "aa" map to the value 1, even though its index in array1 is 0.  Offsetting the computed index by 1 will fix this:

```
int[] indicies = array2.Select(n => Array.IndexOf(array1, n) + 1).ToArray();
```

With this modification an element not found in array1 will result in an index of 0 instead of -1, of course.

Comment: If it does... this answer will still solve the problem, right? :)

Comment: Except that the `homework` tag has specific guidance `Homework means the question is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer.`.  Then again, he did not use that tag (but it does feel like homework).

Comment: Well, then consider this answer for future visitors who are not doing homework.  :)

Comment: Yep.  Plus if it is homework at that level, a professor should not just accept a Linq statement without the student demonstrating they know what Linq is doing on their behalf.

Comment: My university didn't let me test out of the intro-level CS classes, so this is exactly the sort of crap I would throw in all over the place just to make grading my work a bit more exciting.  I got lots of "but we didn't learn about this feature yet, why are you using it?"  Yeah, I guess the compiler doesn't care about the curriculum, huh?  Gosh... I'd hate to have me as a student.

Comment: The results given by this answer are off by one.  Note the example in the question: "the string bb in array2 is in second position of array1 so the output should be 2".  However, `IndexOf(array1, "bb")` will return `1`.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, I've added to my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is homework or a similar learning exercise, here's some guidance:

`array2` seems to be input values for which you want to find a position.

`array1` seems to be the reference array you use for determining where an element is positioned.

- Loop through each element of `array2`.  Let's call the element `elem`.
- For each `elem`, find the index in `array1`
- Add that index to a new array

Have a look at [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) to understand how to figure out the index of `elem` in the reference array.

Comment: Suggest "find the index" instead of "test the index" as the latter implies that there will be some form of comparison or is-non-zero test, when there doesn't need to be one.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't coded C# in awhile but..

Use nested for loops to check to see if array1 contains the specified string in array 2, and if it does, store the index array1 is on in the array you will be using to store all indexes.

And as for the array to store the output, give it the size of array2.

Good luck! :)